# INSERT table alias not recognised in the OUTPUT clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Why is the INSERT table alias not recognised in the OUTPUT/INSERTED line?

EDIT: The linking table needs to be populated with new  @Data_Table.Id (INSERTED.id, works), and the @NewData_Table.ObjectId (errors). SO that a 'linking table', with a foreign key relationship from @Data_Table to @Tmp_Link_Table can be created.

EDIT:

```
--Expected Output
--ObjectId  DataId
--11          3
--12          4
--13          5
--14          6

DECLARE @NewData_Table TABLE
(   [Data] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    ObjectId INT NOT NULL)

DECLARE @Tmp_Link_Table TABLE
(   ObjectId INT NOT NULL,
    DataId INT NOT NULL)

DECLARE @Data_Table TABLE
(   Id INT NOT NULL Identity(1,1),
    Data VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL)

-- create new objects
INSERT INTO @NewData_Table (ObjectId, Data) VALUES (11,'Data 1')
INSERT INTO @NewData_Table (ObjectId, Data) VALUES (12,'Data 2')
INSERT INTO @NewData_Table (ObjectId, Data) VALUES (13,'Data 3')
INSERT INTO @NewData_Table (ObjectId, Data) VALUES (14,'Data 4')
SELECT * FROM @NewData_Table

-- create some data
INSERT INTO @Data_Table (Data) VALUES ('Data One')
INSERT INTO @Data_Table (Data) VALUES ('Data Two')
--@Data_Table BEFORE
SELECT * FROM @Data_Table
```

**--Q!: Why "Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 27 The multi-part identifier "d.ObjectId" could not be bound."?**

```
INSERT INTO @Data_Table (Data)    OUTPUT d.ObjectId, INSERTED.Id INTO @Tmp_Link_Table (ObjectId, DataId)
SELECT d.Data
FROM @NewData_Table AS d 

--@Data_Table AFTER
SELECT * FROM @Data_Table

--Linked table from INSERT
SELECT * FROM @Tmp_Link_Table
```

REF: [OUTPUT Clause (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql#examples)

Comment: Change it to `OUTPUT INSERTED.Data, INSERTED.Id`

Comment: Edited to explain why INSERTED.Data is not the answer.

Comment: Accepted Answer also, posted on https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/466e90f4-b4b9-401a-8043-d3309ea0e7b0/question-of-insert-with-output-clause?forum=transactsql in 2011 :-)

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, with `INSERT` statements, you cannot output a column that is not one of the inserted columns (though I can't seem to find a reference in the documentation that explains this).

There is a way to get around this, by using a merge statement.

For example, change this part:

```
INSERT INTO @Data_Table (Data)    OUTPUT d.ObjectId, INSERTED.Id INTO @Tmp_Link_Table (ObjectId, DataId)
SELECT d.Data
FROM @NewData_Table AS d
```

To this:

```
MERGE @Data_Table AS DT
USING @NewData_Table AS NDT
ON 1 = 2 -- This never matches...
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN -- So this is always true...
    INSERT (Data) 
    VALUES (NDT.Data) 
    OUTPUT NDT.ObjectId, INSERTED.id 
    INTO @Tmp_Link_Table (ObjectId, DataId);
```

Comment: That's an amazing solution. I've found a similar question: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2d5ff792-a90a-4adc-a687-5c76ee22a5fe/include-column-from-table-in-select-in-an-insert-output-clause?forum=transactsql. I'll quote your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your table schema and query as below to work:

```
DECLARE @NewData_Table TABLE
(   [Data] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    ObjectId INT NOT NULL
)

DECLARE @Tmp_Link_Table TABLE
(   ObjectId INT NOT NULL,
    DataId INT NOT NULL
)

DECLARE @Data_Table TABLE
(   Id INT NOT NULL Identity(1,1),
    Data INT
)

-- create new objects
INSERT INTO @NewData_Table (ObjectId, Data) VALUES (11,66)
INSERT INTO @NewData_Table (ObjectId, Data) VALUES (12,88)
INSERT INTO @NewData_Table (ObjectId, Data) VALUES (13,99)
INSERT INTO @NewData_Table (ObjectId, Data) VALUES (14,44)
SELECT * FROM @NewData_Table

-- create some data
INSERT INTO @Data_Table (Data) VALUES (44)
INSERT INTO @Data_Table (Data) VALUES (55)
--@Data_Table BEFORE
SELECT * FROM @Data_Table

INSERT INTO @Data_Table (Data)    OUTPUT INSERTED.Data, INSERTED.Id INTO @Tmp_Link_Table (ObjectId, DataId)
SELECT d.Data
FROM @NewData_Table AS d 

--@Data_Table AFTER
SELECT * FROM @Data_Table

--Linked table from INSERT
SELECT * FROM @Tmp_Link_Table
```

**Output (@Tmp_Link_Table):**

[image]

Comment: I think this doesn't work "INSERT INTO Data_Table (Data)    OUTPUT INSERTED.Data, INSERTED.Id INTO Tmp_Link_Table (ObjectId, DataId)"

Comment: ok maybe my mistake. ill try this and if working ill vote you up

Comment: can i know reason for downVote?

Comment: it doesn't insert the ObjectId into the TmpLinkTable, your change just get's rid of the error message.

Comment: @OzBob : It add ObjectId in TmpLinkTable, check output.

Comment: @sandip-patel you added the .Data column into the ObjectId column. See 'expected output' in edited question.